# Lucky Number Eight - Hackerrank-W28

Tags: python, algorithm, puzzle

Given an n-digit positive integer, count and print the number of sub-sequences formed by concatenating the given number's digits that are divisible by 8. As the result can be large, print the result modulo (10**9 + 7).
the question can be read [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w28/challenges/lucky-number-eight)

Looks simple and i tried to solve it. My approach, tried to keep track of all 3 digit, 2 digit and 1 digit numbers divisible by 8. since any number with last 3 digits divisible by 8 is exactly divisible by 8, i tired to keep a tree for 3 digit and track occurrences (2**p, p=number of preceding characters gives number of sequences), but this was not right since i could not handle some scenarios where digits are interleaved (example 9868).

After the contest is over, i was looking for elegant solution since the Editorial was not clear enough. I came across one, but could not understand whats going on. Could someone explain the math behind the following solution ?

```
#!/bin/python3
import sys

# n = int(input().strip())
# number = input().strip()

n = 10
# number = "0123456789" #81
number = "1234567890" #109

# n = 5
# number = "9868" #5

mods = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
P = 10**9 + 7
for k in number:
   m = int(k) % 8
   new_mods = mods[:]
   new_mods[m] += 1
   for i in range(8):
      new_index = (i*10+m)%8
      new_mods[new_index] = (new_mods[new_index] + mods[i]) % P
   mods = new_mods

print(mods[0])
```

[ideone link](https://ideone.com/RHbfWP)

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. Check Python tutorial and get back here in case of any specific issue

Comment: My question is not about how its done, i am asking why its done this way, whats the math behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the algorithm is to incrementally process prefixes of the given number and for every prefix and every `r` from `0` to `7` to calculate the number of subsequences of that prefix that form a number equal to `r` modulo `8`.

Let `[n₀n₁...nₓ]` be the input number.

Let `S(i, r)` be the number of subsequences of the prefix `[n₀n₁...nᵢ]` that form a number equal to `r` modulo `8`.

In order to calculate `S(i+1, r)` for `0 ≤ r ≤ 7` we only need to know `S(i, r)` for `0 ≤ r ≤ 7`. That's what makes it possible to process the digits one by one in linear time.

There are 3 kinds of subsequences of `[n₀n₁...nᵢ₊₁]`:

1. Subsequences that don't contain `nᵢ₊₁`.

   - For every subsequence `[a...b]` of `[n₀n₁...nᵢ]` there is an equal subsequence of `[n₀n₁...nᵢ₊₁]`.
   - We take them into account by adding `S(i, r)` to `S(i+1, r)` for every `r` from `0` to `7`.
2. Subsequences that contain `nᵢ₊₁` and at least one digit before it.

   - For every subsequence `[a...b]` of `[n₀n₁...nᵢ]` that is equal to `r` modulo `8` there is a subsequence `[a...bnᵢ₊₁]` of `[n₀n₁...nᵢ₊₁]` that is equal to `(r*10+nᵢ₊₁)%8` modulo `8` (since `[a...bnᵢ₊₁] = 10*[a...b] + nᵢ₊₁`).
   - We take them into account by adding `S(i, r)` to `S(i+1, (r*10+nᵢ₊₁)%8)` for every `r` from `0` to `7`.
3. One-digit subsequence `[nᵢ₊₁]`.

   - We take it into account by adding `1` to `S(i+1, nᵢ₊₁ % 8)`.

In the code you quoted:

- `S(i, 0), ..., S(i, 7)` is `mods` — the array of 8 numbers for the previous prefix.
- `S(i+1, 0), ..., S(i+1, 7)` is `new_mods` — the array of 8 numbers for the current prefix.
- `nᵢ₊₁` is `k` — the last digit of the current prefix.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, a sequence is divisible by 8 only if last 3 digits are divisible by 8, but seems like code is considering only 1 digit and 2 digit numbers "(r*10+nᵢ₊₁)%8" so where/how are we making sure the sequence is divisible by 8 (last 3 digits of any sequence formed)?

Comment: The fact that a sequence is divisible by 8 only if its last 3 digits are divisible by 8 is (somewhat surprisingly) not used in this algorithm. It would work just as well with any other number.

Comment: @bicepjai Suppose we already processed 10 digits and the next digit `n₁₀=5`. Now `mods[r]` stores the number of subsequences (of any length) of the prefix `[n₀n₁...n₉]` that are equal to `r` modulo 8. For every such subsequence `[a...b]` there is a subsequence `[a...b5]` that is equal to `10*r+5` modulo 8. That's why we make the assignment `new_mods[(10*r+5)%8] += mods[r]`. The lengths of those subsequences are never explicitly considered.

Comment: thanks for clarification, i had my mind set on the math divisibility rule of 8 when solving it. Thanks for the explanation.